# Chrome Popup Blocker Breaks Link_to Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I noticed today that delete will not work in chrome when this popup blocker is enabled.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmpeeekfhbmikbdhlpjbfmnpgcbeggic

When I click Destroy it would block the "are you sure?" confirm popup and send a Get request to the object I want to delete.

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', group, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
```

This failure is silent and annoying if the users don't realize what is happening.

Is there anyway to get around the popup blocker or at least warn the user that their popup blocker is keeping them from deleting the object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not due to Rails : the extension you mentioned **alters** Chrome default behavior. If you want your application to be this-particular-extension-proof you should implement your own confirmation mechanism, using jQuery UJS.

The issue is that on the current UJS master, the confirm method returns in a **synchronous** fashion (so it won't wait for interaction with the user unless used with the built-in confirmation pop-up). There's a pull request for that issue [here](https://github.com/akzhan/jquery-ujs/commit/fba4ee35041c1db92672dbadb2502ba96d51ef00). Rails UJS code can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js).

The other option is to remove the confirm option and use jQuery to implement your confirmation process from scratch.